# Ensure requireJS conditional module loaded

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm trying to use requireJS in an existing project. I have an App module that has information about current locale, url ... and want load another module if current locale is something special:

```
// App.js
define([], function() {
    return {
        setEnv: function(obj) { //obj: {locale:'en'}
            this.env = obj;
            that = this;
            if( this.env.locale == 'fa' )
                require(['locale/fa'], function(fa) {
                    that.number = fa.number
                };
            else
                this.number = function( n ) { return n+'' }
        }
    }
});
```

Locale files are like:

```
// locale/fa.js
define([], function() {
    var enToFaDigit(n) { // a function converts a number to persian representation };
    // more stuff
    return {
        number: enToFaDigit
    };
});
```

Now the problem is i don't know when App module loaded `number` method. If i was sure `locale/fa` module *should* load at some point, i could wrap it using `require(['locale/fa']` or use shim. Currently I'm using old blocking way to load appropriate `locale/*.js` and PHP to choose right file, without problem. But i want know how requireJS programmers write similar code. Probably there is some way better than this code:

```
require(['app'], function(App) {
    if(App.env.locale == 'fa') {
        require(['locale/fa'], function(fa) {
            // 8-S
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a case for the [i18n plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#i18n)! I believe you are allowed to define functions as well as strings. I would define a bundle like so:

```
//nls/formatters.js
define({
    root: {
        currency: function(num) {
            // implementation for default currency format (en-US often)
        }
    },
    "fa": true
})
```

And here's your Persian override:

```
//nls/fa/formatters.js
define({
    currency: function(num) {
        // implementation for farsi currency format
    }
})
```

In your app.js file:

```
require(['app','i18n!nls/formatters'], function(App, Formatters) {
    Formatters.currency(5.00); // works!
});
```

Comment: Thanks, It's absolutely useful, but my question is more general, not just for localization. BTW i will accept your answer if no-one suggests more general way. (My problem is i don't know which localization should be loaded till `App` constructed. With `i18n!` i should set locale prior `App` loading.)

Comment: The plugin accesses the navigator.language property, so it reads the locale on the user's computer! If that's not appropriate for your use, you can make a build.js file which specifies it. To answer your question more generally, though, conditional requires *appear* to work, but actually cause all code branches to be required (provided that you require("") a string literal, and not a preset variable.)

Comment: `navigator.language` (Which is read-only AFAIK) or `build.js` doesn't solve any problem, because they both set locale before `require.config`. no way to change locale [after that](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/213).

Comment: @Reith the idea is that you would build separate compiled files for each locale, which is a common solution, and then conditionally require them in your final build.